# Cannot do operations on a non-existent table

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

Facing issue while using DynamoDb with Spring Boot for storing data.

It gives me the following error.
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 7ffd4509-e444-4569-8c81-d4e7a1c218ef)

I have started a local instance of DynamoDb using the following command on a windows machine

**java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 8001 -sharedDb**

Created DynamoDBMapper for interacting with DB

```
@Bean
public DynamoDBMapper mapper() {
    return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBConfig());
}

public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBConfig() {
    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
    .withEndpointConfiguration(new 
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(awsDynamoDBEndPoint, awsRegion))
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new 
    BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
    .build();
}
```

And called mapper using @Autowiring

```
@Autowired
private DynamoDBMapper mapper;
```

When I try to add data using

mapper.save(person);

it gives an error saying **Cannot do operations on a non-existent table**

Please give me some idea where I am missing the trick here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The status code you get is 400 that means bad request.
Please check the whether the table is present in your local instance.

Comment: The table is present, but where I need to pass the table name while creating DynamoDbMapper object?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause might be because of aws-cli and the application using different aws profiles (credential and region). It will create different db files and use different db files when aws-cli and application connect to dynamodb local.

Please use the below approach to debug.

1. You must use sharedDB to start your docker instance.
   `docker run -p 8000:8000 -v $(pwd)/local/dynamodb:/data/ amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /data`
2. Please check the aws profile u have created (`aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key`) . Use these same values in your application to connect to the docker dynamoDB instance .

Answer (score 0):

In your Person.java(Model class) check the table name. Table names are case sensitive for DynamoDB

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Person")
```

Or

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "person")
```